# How to add members permanently in multiuserchat room and invite members with asmack xmpp?

Tags: android, xmpp

In my chat application I want to implement group chat functionality.For that I have created rooms with asmack Xmpp successfully,But problem is that invitation was not received by group members and when any group member went offline after join group than will leave from group.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP Multi-User chat protocol is presence based. It means that when a user (JID) is not online, it will not be in the MUC room. This is by design in XMPP MUC Protocol.

Reference: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#exit

You need to use other approach to simulate persistent chat room: Pubsub node, custom protocol, for example.

Comment: I already visited this link,but not getting any solution for create persistance group with keep member in room.if one time connection lost than member leave from room and also problem of send invitation to friends for join group

Comment: MUC chat room can be persistent, but they work like IRC. Users are in the chat room only while they are online.